# SimpleComboBox : text alignment GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using simpleComboBox for dropdown list.But its not working properly.he data in dropdown moves to left when I select the item.I have attached the image that how does it look
Please help.
[image: textAlignment]

```
final SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
combo.setForceSelection(true);
combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
combo.setFieldLabel("Calculation MethodNames  ");

combo.add(cList);
```

Comment: are you using GXT?

Comment: which version of GXT are you using?

Comment: it's gxt 2.2.4 version

Comment: That's really old. Which GWT version are you using?

Comment: I am using gxt-2.2.4-gwt22.jar

Comment: It looks like, that there were an issue: Take a look here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?117350-Option-list-elect-button-of-ComboBox-in-Chrome-is-shifted. Hope that helps.

Comment: doesn't look like browser issue.

Comment: The problem was, that there are used old resources. Have you copied the right css & images?

Comment: I am not using any css files in this project

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input width is getting distorted. I'm not sure what's going on yet. Although if you want to modify the input element css, which css might be able to be used to fix the issue, first retrieve the element.

`ELement e gxtWidget.el().select("input").getItem(0).cast()` iirc... Then use that to getStyle().set(something) that will either change the width or align the text.